# Python Imaging Library (PIL) Decoder jpeg not available — how to fix?

Tags: macos, python

I've got error which is generated by PIL when I trying to process jpg-images: `Python Imaging Library (PIL) Decoder jpeg not available`.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIL is missing `libjpeg` library.

To install it:

1. Go to http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
2. Unpack this package and `cd` to the unpacked folder `cd ~/Downloads/jpeg-8c`
3. Compile it:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   ```
4. Then install: `sudo make install`

But PIL still can't find library. Now you need to reinstall it:

1. Uninstall pil (if you instlled it with pip, just type `sudo pip uninstall pil`)
2. Download [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), unpack it and move to source folder.
3. Now open setup.py in your code editor
4. Replace `JPEG_ROOT = None` with `JPEG_ROOT = libinclude("/usr/local")`
5. Enjoy! Now it works!

Comment: works perfect.. +1 for wonderful answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also install it from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). They have PIL for several versions of Python.

```
py-pil @1.1.7 (python, graphics)
    Python Imaging Library

py24-pil @1.1.7 (python, graphics)
    Python Imaging Library

py25-pil @1.1.7 (python, graphics)
    Python Imaging Library

py26-pil @1.1.7 (python, graphics)
    Python Imaging Library

py27-pil @1.1.7 (python, graphics)
    Python Imaging Library
```

Check out the site for how to install MacPorts, then just type `sudo port install py-pil` (or one of the other versions, such as `py27-pil`). Wait a while and you should have a working PIL, assuming you use the version of Python for which the PIL was installed.